# XmlSerializer.Deserialize - проблема со смешанным содержимым (mixed content)

Tags: c#, сериализация

Всем привет.

Хочу десериализовать следующую строку:

```
<summary>
    Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:PrimarkPOSAutoTests.WinAppDriver"/> class.
</summary>
```

Падает на этой строке со следующим исключением:

```
XmlException: 'Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType.
```

Хочу десериализовать эту строку как сплошной string. Можно ли так сделать? Или сериализатор путается из-за тэга `<see/>`?

P.S. Поле для хранения этого текста:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "summary")]
public string Summary { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, надо понять, что содержимое тэга `<summary>` - это **не** строка! Это структурированный текст, который должен быть представлен в виде фрагмента DOM.

Простейший способ считать его - это сделать свойство типа `object`:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "summary")]
public object Summary { get; set; } // реальный тип - XmlNode[]
```

Теперь в свойство `Summary` попадёт массив `XmlNode[]` из трёх узлов - `XmlText`, `XmlElement` и снова `XmlText`.

Однако, работать с таким нетипизированным полем неудобно, поэтому можно попытаться добавить больше типизации. К сожалению, просто поставить `XmlNode[]` в качестве типа не получится, а значит нужен отдельный класс:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "summary")]
public Summary Summary { get; set; }

public class Summary 
{
    [XmlAnyElement, XmlText]
    public XmlNode[] Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

Если вы не желаете работать с DOM - можно завести свои типы для десериализации:

```
public class Summary
{
    [XmlElement("see", Type = typeof(See))]
    [XmlText(Type = typeof(string))]
    public object[] Nodes { get; set; } // реальный тип - (See | string)[]
}

public class See
{
    [XmlAttribute("cref")]
    public string CRef { get; set; }
}
```

Наконец, если вам обязательно требуется получить именно строковое представление - можно сделать вот так:

```
[XmlElement("summary")]
public RawXml Summary { get; set; }

public class RawXml : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Content { get; set; }

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema() => null;

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        Content = reader.ReadInnerXml();
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteRaw(Content);
    }
}
```

Но без нужды так лучше не делать: вы рискуете запутаться в префиксах и пространствах имён.